# in C++, what do the underscore signs in the multi-inheritance classes mean?

Tags: c++

here is the code:

```
PiGenerator::PiGenerator(PP_Instance instance)
: pp::Instance(instance),
  graphics_2d_context_(NULL),
  pixel_buffer_(NULL),
  flush_pending_(false),
  quit_(false),
  compute_pi_thread_(0),
  pi_(0.0) {
  pthread_mutex_init(&pixel_buffer_mutex_, NULL);
}
```

Or is this even multi-inheritance? Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's (probably) just a convention: often, `private` variables are declared with a tailing underscore, so that one can easily recognize them.

Answer (score 4):

No, that isn't specific to multiple inheritance. That's just the naming convention the original programmer decided to make.

Answer (score 1):

Those are actually *fields* of the class `PiGenerator`. They all constitute the *initialization list*, which provides values to the various fields of the class before the constructor is entered. In this example, `pp::Instance` is the only base class constructor involved, and the rest are field initializations.

Comment: Wrong. The initialization list uses almost the same syntax for members (fields) and base classes. There's one big exception: member names can't be qualified. I.e. `pp::Instance` cannot be a member, but has to be a base class.

Comment: Oops, you're right. For some reason I read that as `ppInstance` without the colons. Updating my answer.

Comment: Sorry, still wrong. The initializer list includes both fields and base classes. So you can't say that "the rest are the initialization list". In particular, there is no required order. You may freely mix initializers for base classes and members within the initializer list.

Comment: Oh hush you. It's Labour Day, you want I should be thinking? :P